# R: How to get rid of default data and values stored in global environment

Tags: r, environment-variables, global-variables, rstudio, default

Every time I open my laptop R, the same data and values (data tables and variables I used in the past) keep on appearing, and it's annoying to `rm()` them every time I open a new file to work on something else. My question is: 1) Is there a way to reset or set default data and variables in global environment? For example, if I'm working on `file1`, I want to use data table `data1`, `data2`, and `data3` and variable `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`. It'd be nice if I can store these set of data and variables for `file1`specifically and simply call them instead of loading the data and running the codes every time I open the file.

Thank you!

Comment: RStudio's [Projects](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects) feature (with saving your workspaces) would give you something like this

Comment: Remove .RData from your home directory: it's hidden file which is always loaded whenever R starts.

Answer (score 3):

In RStudio, press the button with the broom icon to remove all objects from the environment. Include hidden objects. Then, quit RStudio and make sure to save the workspace image to ~/.Rdata. This should fix your problem. When you open RStudio again, the Global Environment should be empty.